# Binding click events to a Tab in Ext JS

Tags: javascript, extjs, tabs, extjs4, tabpanel

Aloha again, SO.

I'm busy working on a project that is pretty much all ExtJS for the frontend work. I'm using version 4.0.0, presuming that is something necessary to know. I've got some code along the following:

```
panel = Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel",{
        //initializing stuffs
})
```

A few of those then

```
 tabs = Ext.create("Ext.tab.Panel", {
        //initialize config
        items: [
               //the panels
        ]
  })
```

Now my big problem here is, I need to be able to bind an event to the actual tabs. I'm aware of being able to bind events to the tab panel and tab bar,  but I need to actually bind the click event to one of the tabs in the panel. I tried something along the lines of this:

```
panel = Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel", {
        //initializing stuffs
        listeners: {
                 click: {
                        fn: function() {
                            console.log("in click listener for panel")
                        }
                  }
         }
 })
```

However, the problem is, based on what I can tell, that binds to the actual panel itself, and not to the tab up in the tab bar. On an interesting side note, it actually doesn't even bind to the actual panel, as far as functionality is concerned, because I never see that console log information.

In any case, would any of you here happen to know how to bind events directly to the tabs? Or even how to get access to the tabs directly? I've been sifting through the ExtJS API docs, but I still can't find anything, so, it'd be awesome if someone here could help! :D

Just to make it clear, I'm not trying to hook into the tab changing. I'm trying to hook into the actual click event of clicking the tab, because I am going to be checking if it is the middle mouse button being clicked so I can close the tab if it is.

Answer (score 2):

I put this on a tab inside a tab panel in ExtJS 3. Something similar should work in 4.

```
listeners: {
    activate: function() {
        var me = this;
        Ext.fly(this.ownerCt.getTabEl(this)).on({
            click: function() {
                me.loadProducts();
            }
        });
    },
    single: true
},

loadProducts: function() {
    this.load({
    url: 'products.jsp',
    params: {
        caseID: window.caseID
    },
    scripts: true
});
```

Comment: You should look at the tabBar property on the tab panel in Ext4. Use the index of the tab to find it from the tabBar items and attach a click handler to it.

Comment: I ended up finding out what I need to find out; after you add in a tab to the tab bar, it adds a property to the component that you added in called tab that represents the tab button, so, I just binded onmousedown to that and everything is peachy.

Comment: @Sir mXe : i m intrested in doing something similar to urs, but i couldn really understund what u did, newbis in extjs im afraid, could u please explain further, an example would be welcome too,thanks in advance

Comment: @astrocybernaute I don't suppose you found an answer, did you?

Answer (score 1):

You can add listeners to [TabPanel](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.tab.Panel.html) itself that listen to `beforetabchange` and/or `tabchange`

Comment: The problem is that beforetabchange and tabchange do not address the issue of interpreting clicks. I'm going to be setting it up to bind to the click event and from there, determine if the middle mouse button is being pressed. I'll be sure to update the initial question; thanks for the suggestion though :D